# Индексация переменной без выхода за границы перечисления

Tags: c, enum

```
int8_t state;

enum light_state {OFF, White, Red, Blue, Green, Pink, Color, Random};

// Событие может происходить до 100 000 раз.
//
// Flag выставлен, как сделать переменную, чтоб глубина
// (длина) была Enum?
//
// Или light_state использовать для контроля состояния:
//
//     0, __, __, __|> __, __, 7 — и дальше по кругу
//
// Как я понял из литературы, перечисление — это список указателей
// искомой длины на CONST INDEX[CONST МАСИВОВ[]].
//
// lite <= light_st можно ли light_st++ ??????????????????? 7>>++>>0
if (event)
    state++;
```

Создавать переменную в 3-бит можно, но не всегда, если число 191. Битовую маску накладывать на каждой итерации и проверять переполнение.

Может, я что-то не знаю? Подскажите.

`Type_def_типа enum{...}` переменная `State` той же глубины.

Answer (score 2):

Есть несколько вариантов.

1. Один из них — как вы догадались сами — накладывать битовую маску с помощью побитового умножения при каждом инкременте, чтобы значение не выходило за заданный диапазон:

   ```c
   state = (state + 1) & 0x111;
   ```

   Такой вариант подойдет только если в перечислении 2<sup>N</sup> − 1 элементов<sup>†</sup>, зато это самый быстрый вариант — все выражение компилируется всего в 4 инструкции:

   ```
   movzx   eax, BYTE PTR state[rip]
   add     eax, 1
   and     eax, 17
   mov     BYTE PTR state[rip], al
   ```
2. Использовать оператор взятия остатка от деления `%`:

   ```c
   state = (state + 1) % StatesCount;
   ```

   Если в перечислении 2<sup>N</sup> − 1 элементов, то компилятор оптимизирует так, что все это считается без деления обычным побитовым сдвигом:

   ```
   movzx   eax, BYTE PTR state[rip]
   movzx   eax, al
   add     eax, 1
   cdq
   shr     edx, 29
   add     eax, edx
   and     eax, 7
   sub     eax, edx
   mov     BYTE PTR state[rip], al
   ```
3. Использовать условие:

   ```c
   state = (state == StatesCount - 1) ? 0 : state + 1;
   ```

   Обычно, ветвление плохо сказывается на производительности, но как вариант можно сделать и так.

---

<sup>† Думаю, не стоит говорить что нумерация элементов перечисления должна начинаться с 0, а номер каждого следующего элемента должен быть на 1 больше предыдущего.</sup>